# Regexp_replace returning only upper case characters (ignoring spaces)

Tags: sql, db2, regexp-replace

Example:

**Column:** Name

**Value:**  Leonardo Di Caprio

I'd like to only extract the *upper case* characters: *LDC*

So without the spaces.

I have a DB2-database. My suggestion would be to use regexp_substr.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: my suggestion is to write a function that get string as a parameter and return upper case characters and use it in select like ```select a,b,function(Name) FROM x;```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     Select  REGEXP_REPLACE( 'Leonardo Di Caprio', '[a-z ]', '' )
     From table;
```

Check for testing output

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b6773/2

Comment: This option exclude lower case characters and whitespaces. But special characters are included. "Iréne Juliana" in your solution would be "IéJ". And thats not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  S
, REGEXP_REPLACE (' ' || S, '(?<! )[:upper:]|[^[:upper:]]', '')
FROM (VALUES 'Iréne Juliana', 'Iréne-Juliana Smith', 'Leonardo Di Caprio') T (S)
```

Comment: Thanx Mark! Works. But if the name is like "Iréne-Juliana Smith" I only want the "IS" capitals. Do you have a solution for that issue? So exclude "-Juliana" from it.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please, check.

Comment: Thanx, works! One last question: 'María de los Angeles', is there a way to include this example in your answer? So I get 'MdlA' as initials?